# Laravel 5 fails to pass variable to all views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with passing variable (data) to all Views. I created BaseController that extends default Laravel controller and "global" variables are defined there. When I extend other controller with BaseController i got error that variable is not defined. Does someone knows where's the problem?

Here is code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Sentry;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use View;

class BaseController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $obavijesti="Other data";
        $izbornici="Some data";
        View::share ( 'izbornici', $izbornici );
        View::share ( 'obavjesti', $obavjesti );
        }
   }

class AdminController extends BaseController {
     .
     .
     .
      echo '<pre>';var_dump($izbornici);echo '</pre>';//Error pop ups here

     .
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: `View::share` only makes the variable globally available **in the view**

Comment: In what controller method are you trying to do this: echo `'<pre>';var_dump($izbornici);echo '</pre>';//Error pop ups here`

Comment: You are doing something wrong here. view::share() is used for sharing a piece of data across all views not controller

Comment: oh, sorry for my mistake. Error triggers when in default.blade.php @Digitlimit . I will edit my post

Comment: The child class needs to call the constructor of the parent class, e.g. parent::__constructor().  Your variables will then be shared to all views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing something wrong here. view::share() is used for sharing a piece of data across all views not controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Sentry;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use View;

//If you wish to get these variables in your other controllers you do this:

class BaseController extends Controller {

    public $obavijesti="Other data";
    public $izbornici="Some data";

    public function __construct() {
       View::share ( 'izbornici', $this->izbornici );
       View::share ( 'obavjesti', $this->obavjesti );
    }  

}

class AdminController extends BaseController {

    //if you have a constructor in other controllers you need call constructor of parent controller (i.e. BaseController) like so:

    public function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function Index(){
      echo $this->obavijesti;
    }

}
```

**You can also use a composer to share variables to views**

```
//1. Create a composer file at app\Composers\AdminComposer.php
//NB: create "app\Composers" if does not exists

//2. Inside AdminComposer.php add this.


<?php namespace App\Composers;

class AdminComposer
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function compose($view)
    {
        //Add your variables
        $view->with('izbornici',      'Other data')
            ->with('obavjesti',       'Some other data');
    }
}

//3. In you controller do this:

<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
//NB: I removed your BaseController because I believe the issue is coming from //there

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Sentry;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use View;

class AdminController extends Controller{


    public function __construct(){
        //Lets use AdminComposer to share variables to adminpage.blade.php view

        View::composers([
            'App\Composers\AdminComposer'  => array('adminpage')
        ]);

    }

    public function Index(){
        return view('adminpage');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed code from controller but when I want to echo it in View I got undefinied variable

Comment: @jureispro Did you pass the variable into the view before you `echo` it?

Comment: @mininoz Logic is that I want to pass that variable automaticlly on all views insted of manually passing it over and over

Comment: Thank you for your help but I got  Undifnied variable izbornici when I am using View. Is there way to automaticly pass variable to all views? I don't want to pass same variable over and over for every view I create

Comment: @jureispro Please check the updated answer. You can use view composer as another solution

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you're going to want a combination of what you have, and the other answer posted here.

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {
    protected $obavijesti = 'Other data';
    protected $izbornici = 'Some data';

    public function __construct() {
        View::share('obavjesti', $this->obavjesti);
        View::share('izbornici', $this->izbornici);
    }
}
```

Then in all of your views, you have access to the variables `$obavjesti` and `$izbornici`. Now in your other controllers, anything that extends `BaseController` can do the following:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        echo $this->ixbornici;
        echo $this->obavjesti;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will work inside controller but my problem is inside View. I can't access variable "izbornici" inside blade.template...

Comment: This will work inside the view and the controller, `View::share()` makes it available in the view.