# laravel 5.1: How to share a collection in all views?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-5.1

I need to share a collection in all of my views. This collection contain the website news:

```
$news=NewsStory::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where your controller?

Comment: You can use a view composer

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599690/laravel-5-fails-to-pass-variable-to-all-views/29600028#29600028

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share [View Data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-data) between all views. Just add this one line to the `boot()` method in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`:

```
view()->share('news', NewsStory::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is just what I needed.